# warning: unnecessary parentheses around assigned value

Tags: rust

The following code:

```
use clap::Parser;

#[derive(Parser, Default, Debug)]
struct Cli {
    #[clap(default_value_t=("some_value".to_string()))]
    /// Some description
    text_option: String,
}

fn main() {
    let args = Cli::parse();
    println!("{:?}", args);
}
```

gives me a warning that the brackets around `"some_value".to_string()` are unnecessary. If I remove them, I get `error: expected ,` at the `.`.

How can I fix the errors/warnings?

Comment: Related [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/104457) and [question on the clap repo](https://github.com/clap-rs/clap/discussions/4676) You might be able to use `String::from("some_value")` or use `default_value="some_value"` like suggested on the question.

Comment: Thanks. That works. If you add it as an answer, I'll accept it.